# How to find if one column is contained in another array column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 columns with the following schema in a pyspark dataframe

```
('pattern', 'array<struct<pattern:string,positions:array<int>>>')

('distinct_patterns', 'array<array<struct<pattern:string,positions:array<int>>>>')
```

I want to find those rows where pattern is there in distinct patterns

Comment: [How to make good reproducible spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Comment: Some sample data will be helpful